# Javascript quote escape giving bugs

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print a button to a div that would pass a variable MyVar(string), or, to be precise, it's value, as a parameter to a function addfr(). The code:

```
 document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML="<button onclick=\"addfr(\""+MyVar+"\")\">Add as friend</button>";
```

Instead of the expected

```
    <button onclick="addfr("MyVar")">Add as friend</button>"
```

I get:

```
    <button onclick="addfr(" MyVar")"="">
```

What is happening here? Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: The final solution is, for those interested:

```
  <button onclick=\"addfr(&quot;"+MyVar+"&quot;)\">Add as friend</button>
```

Comment: Why not just use single quotes instead of double quotes inside the string (or vice versa)? Eliminates the issue completely.

Comment: Nop, tried that, the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be HTML escaped. Try using `&quot;` in place of `\"`.

Comment: Yup, that was what I needed. It partially solved the problem, although I also needed to use \" for it to work fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes instead:

```
document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML="<button onclick=\"addfr('"+MyVar+"')\">Add as friend</button>";
```